# How to pass extra data from the client over to slingshot s3storage?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-slingshot

I'm trying to pass the user id from `FlowRouter.getParam('id');` to the server to upload a file into amazon. This is an admin account so I'm using the `FlowRouter.getParam('id');` to access the correct user's profile information. The problem is I'm not correctly passing the id over so it all just errors and stops working.

How do I pass the id over correctly?

Path `uploadFile.js`

```
let _uploadFileToAmazon = ( file ) => {
  var id = FlowRouter.getParam('id');
  const uploader = new Slingshot.Upload( "uploadProfileImgAdmin", id );
  uploader.send( (file), ( error, url ) => {
    if ( error ) {
      Bert.alert( error.message, "warning" );
      _setPlaceholderText();
    } else {
      _addUrlToDatabase( url );
    }
  });
};
```

Path `server/uploadFile.js`

```
Slingshot.createDirective( "uploadProfileImgAdmin", Slingshot.S3Storage, {
  bucket: "bhr-app",
  region: "ap-southeast-2",
  acl: "public-read",
  authorize: function (id) {
    console.log("user id: ", id);
    return Files.findOne( { "userId": id } );
  },
  key: function ( file ) {
    var user = Meteor.users.findOne( _id: id );

    return "profile-images" + "/" + user.emails[0].address + "/" + file.name;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, in order to get the current user's id, you should use `this.userId` on the server in the `authorize` method and don't simply trust the data passed by the client (to make sure that the user is, in fact, an admin and validate the parameters).

The [meta-context](https://github.com/CulturalMe/meteor-slingshot#add-meta-context-to-your-uploads) added to the upload should be an object (you are passing a string) and it is available as the second parameter of your directive methods.

```js
const uploader = new Slingshot.Upload("uploadProfileImgAdmin", {id});
```

And on the server, your directive's methods get the `file` and the `meta` you passed:

```js
Slingshot.createDirective( "uploadProfileImgAdmin", Slingshot.S3Storage, {
  bucket: "bhr-app",
  region: "ap-southeast-2",
  acl: "public-read",
  authorize: function (file, meta) {
    console.log("user id: ", meta.id);
    // validate meta, make sure that the user is an admin and 
    // return a Boolean or throw an error
  },
  key: function (file, meta) {
    var user = Meteor.users.findOne(meta.id);
    return "profile-images" + "/" + user.emails[0].address + "/" + file.name;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Just to clarify: I'm aware that you can use this.userId to access the current users id on the server.  In this case, admin, is editing another account. So I'm using `FlowRouter.getParam('id');` to pass across that id to the server. If there is a better way I would really like to know. 

Your solution is certainly working, however, it now errors at the `uploader.send( (file), ( error, url ) =>` it says the user isn't authorised. I've tried to add `uploader.send( (file, {id}), ( error, url ) =>` this changes the error to this is not a file.  Thoughts?

Comment: Did you edit the authorize method to validate the input and the admin's identity?

Comment: That was the issue. Thanks heaps!